# Topologies induced by metrics

Tags: real-analysis

When a topology induced by a metric is contained in another topology induced by a different metric how are those metrics related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $d_1$ induces $\tau_1$ and $d_2$ induces $\tau_2$.
Then $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$ iff

$$\forall x \in X: \forall r>0 :\exists s>0 : B_{d_2}(x,s) \subseteq B_{d_1}(x,r)$$

or equivalently:

$$\forall x \in X: \forall r>0 :\exists s>0 : \forall y \in X: d_2(x,y) < s \implies d_1(x,y) < r$$

To see this, use that $x$ must be an $d_2$-interior of its every $d_1$-ball.

Answer (score 1):

Let the metric $d_1$ on $X$ induce a topology $\tau_1$ and $d_2$ induce $\tau_2$. Then

$$\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2 \iff d_1 : X \times X \to [0, \infty) \text{ is continuous with respect to the metric } d_2 \text{ on } X.$$

**Proof.** ($\implies$)

Suppose $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$. It is known that $d_1 : X \times X \to [0, \infty)$ is continuous with respect to the metric $d_1$ on $X$, that is, with respect to the topology $\tau_1$ on $X$. But $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$, so it is also continuous with respect to $\tau_2$ on $X$, so also with respect to $d_2$.

($\impliedby$)

Let $(x_n) \subseteq X$ be an arbitrary sequence and suppose that $d_2(x_n, x) \to 0$. By continuity of $d_1$ we have that $d_1(x_n, x) \to d_1(x, x) = 0$. Thus $x_n \to x$ in $d_2 \implies x_n \to x$ in $d_1$.

A closed set in a metric space can be characterized as a set $F$ that is closed under limits of sequences, i.e. whenever $(x_n) \subseteq F$ converges to some $x$, we must have that $x \in F$. By the property proved above every set closed in $d_1$ is also closed in $d_2$, hence $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$. $\ \blacksquare$

I doubt, however, that any direct inequalities between the metrics can be derived from the assumption that $\tau_1 \subseteq \tau_2$.

Comment: Technically, you'd need to prove that if $\tau_1\subseteq \tau_2$ then the product topologies on $X\times X$ also have this relationship. But it isn't hard to prove.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I took that as completely obvious, but technically yeah, you're right.

Comment: Yeah, you know I wanted an "order" relation between the metrics well proved, but amazing work, m8

Comment: @JorgeArturoQuiroz It's obvious that the relation is a partial order as $\subseteq$ is a partial order. A question is whether this relation has a name...

Comment: Talking topologicly yes, ⊆ is the partial order, but talking about the metrics, which is that order ?